Cable internet router drops connection for 1 second when the fridge goes off
I have a really irritating issue with the router. The internet cable is plugged to a router, and router is plugged to a PC with a lan cable. So, whenever my fridge goes OFF, router drops internet connection 1 second. I'm 100% sure the issue is not related to anything electrical, because I double checked it:

I checked outlets,they are properly grounded, tested with digital multimeter - no issues with outlets;
Tried running router from an external battery - connection still drops when the fridge goes off;
Changed all cables to shielded cables - connection drops;
Moved the fridge to another room - connection drops;

So the only case when connection doesn't drop when the fridge goes off is plugging the internet cable to a PC directly without using the router at all. So the problem is 100% that router receives some RF / EM interference. What can I do with a router (RMA is not an option) to investigate and possibly fix an issue?

Simplest fix may putting the router on a UPS designed to also work as a "power conditioner".

I'm thinking that if the router powered from a battery is not safe from the fridge's uniqueness, then a power conditioner might not help either.

Are you open to trying another router, at least borrowing one from a friend for a few days? Also, is this fridge one of those AI powered Skynet Wifi-connected fridges?

Nope, simple fridge. I had it for 7 years, but the problem started a month ago.

OK, how about borrowing a router?

Even if I do, getting a new fridge/router is not an option. Are there any shielding options I can try?

At this point, it's anyone's guess. If the router is subject to some interference without being connected to house power, then it's some kind of magnetic or RF interfering through the air directly into the router's guts, and that means you'd need Electronics Engineering SE wizardry to try to diagnose it. Could be the router or the fridge. Thus borrowing a router to see if the problem goes away.

Can you elaborate on what you mean by "running router from an external battery" - was this a "UPS" that has a battery backup but plugs in like a surge protector? In my experience, refrigerator compressor feedback is limited to its immediate area, including its electrical circuit. It'd be more interesting if it happened even when completely electrically isolated from the refrigerator's power.

Most routers use 9-12VDC power, so theoretically you could connect it to the right kind of battery to run it 100% independently. If that works, you need a new router or power conditioning. The kinds of shielding that could be effective against RF interference would also tend to block useful RF signals like wifi.

I used external battery, completely isolated from the fridge power. Also, I disabled wifi antennas in router settings and so far there are no more internet drops (router is still plugged to PC with a cable!). But this is so strange, how is it possible for antennas to receive RF interference and make the router drop CABLE connection?

I think this would be better for Electronics SE, I flagged for a moderator to move the question.

I originally posted this question on electronics.stackexchange.com and it was marked as off-topic and closed.

does the problem occur if you turn off the refrigerator by unplugging it?

Since this only happens as the refrigerator goes off, likely the cause is arcing due to the very high dv/dt (i.e., when a circuit opens across a coil, the faster it opens, the higher the voltage pulse generated). This arcing is also likely damaging the relay, burning its contacts so that it will fail.
The quick and dirty answer is to put EMI/RFI (electromagnetic interference AKA radio-frequency interference) filtering as close to the compressor motor and relays as feasible.

Use clip-on ferrite beads over each wire, as well as around the three-wire line cord, such as these, from Amazon. No wires need be removed to attach -- just unplug fridge, open any panel covering the gubbins, and clip the beads around wires.
You might also add a line EMI filter such as this, from Amazon, which requires installation by someone familiar with electronic repair..

Parts listed were simply examples, not specific recommendations.
So why, "quick and dirty?" Because those parts will not stop arcing, just block the EMI. The part causing the interference might last another seven years, or break tomorrow. To reduce arcing, here are two choices:

Add a passive snubber circuit, i.e., a resistor and capacitor, across relay contacts, where the arcing occurs. This is a DIY project for someone familiar with electronic repair.
Replace the relay that has started arcing. This also calls for familiarity with electronic repair, access to the relay, and a replacement part.

Personally, I'd try the clip-on ferrite chokes and, if that doesn't suffice, add a snubber.

Well, I've already added 4 ferrite bands, as close to the compressor as possible. I can't say it helped much. Perhaps the EMI/RFI is so strong it's not enough. Maybe fixing a fridge is my only option.

Not only the compressor motor, but add beads at the other end of each wire, by the relay (or switch) controlling the motor.

@Anna Add a ferrite bead to the router's power cord as well.
